# Develop GPS application

Tags: gps

I have a Windows 7 tablet pc with GPS facility. I need to develop a GPS application for my tablet pc. How can I do that? Is there any built in API is available for that?
What kind of API do I have to use?
some1 please help.

Comment: Does your tablet pc have Windows 7, or anything else? If anything , which os?

Answer (score 0):

Use the framework 4's Location API, check out samples below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gavingear/archive/2009/11/30/net-4-location-let-s-take-a-look-at-status.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gavingear/archive/2009/11/20/let-s-write-a-simple-net-4-location-aware-application.aspx

http://wotudo.net/blogs/wotudo/archive/2010/02/08/windows-7-setup-gps-for-the-location-api.aspx